# Redirect the page according to the user role after validating user

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been trying to redirect the user that has logged into the system to their respective page after checking their email and password. But i am not sure about the logic behind that coding and when i try it it just response with the else statement. I have tried the validation of the email and password and that works fine and redirects to the correct page, but when i add the user type condition it doesnt work

I have tried including nested if statements, but i am not sure about its logic,it always executes the else statement.

loginControllerServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String password=request.getParameter("pwrd");

        User theUser=loginDbUtil.gettype(email);

        if(loginDbUtil.check(email, password))
        {       
            String p="pharmacist";

            if(theUser.getType()==p)
            {
//              HttpSession session=request.getSession();
//                  session.setAttribute("email", email);
                    response.sendRedirect("medicine.jsp");
            }
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }




    }else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

    }
}
```

loginDbUtil.java

```
public boolean check(String email,String password)
    {
        Connection myConn=null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try
        {
            //get db connection
            myConn=dataSource.getConnection();


            //sql statemtn
            String sql="select email,pass from usertab where email=? and pass=? ";


            myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            //set the param values for user
            myStmt.setString(1, email);
            myStmt.setString(2, password);

            rs=myStmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                return true;  
            }



        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return false;
    }




    public User gettype(String email) {

        User type=null;

        Connection myConn=null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try
        {
            //get db connection
            myConn=dataSource.getConnection();


            //sql statemtn
            String sql="select type from usertab where email=?  ";


            myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            //set the param values for user
            myStmt.setString(1, email);

            rs=myStmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                String t=rs.getString("type");



            type =new User(t);

            }



        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return type;

    }

}
```

What i want is after the email and password is checked then next check for the users data type and redirect them to the correct page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loginControllerServlet.java change this to

```
if(theUser.getType()==p)
```

to this

```
if(theUser.getType().equals(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, I think first of all, you should put the attribute type as an int, there will be less chances to have a type like `Pharmacist` and `pharmacist`.

Then to communicate with database check is correct, but I don't think the same about you getType method, this is what I would suggest to you :

1st : Create one bean (object) User as you seem to have done and put getters and setters, and put a constructor with all the attributes as parameters.

Example :

```
class User {
   
   private int id;
   private String mail;
   private String password;
   private int type;

   public User() {
   }

   public User(int id, String mail, String password, int type) {
      this.id = id;
      this.mail = mail;
      this.password = password;
      this.type = type;
   }
   
   // Getters and setters
}
```

Then you check mail would return directly a user object, so you should have

```
class userDB {

   public User login(String mail, String password) {

      User user = new User();
      String query = "select * from user where mail = ? and password = ?";

      try {

         PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);

         prep.setString(1,mail);
         prep.setString(2,password);

         ResultSet res = res.executeQuery();

         if(res.first) {

            user = new User(res.getInt("id"),res.getString("mail"),res.getString("password"),res.getInt("type"));
            return user;
         } else {
            
            return null;
      
         }

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
 
      }
   }
}
```

And then in you Servlet you can write:

```
class Login extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respons) throws ServletException, IOException {         
    
         this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(your_jsp_relative_path).forward(request, respons);
        
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respons) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    
        String mail = (String) request.getParameter("mail');
        String password = (String) request.getParameter("mail');

        User user = new UserDB().login(mail, password);

        if(user != null){

           int type = user.getType();

           switch(type){

              case 0 :
                   respons.sendRedirect("type_0_page");
              break;
              case 1 :
                   respons.sendRedirect("type_1_page");
              break;
              case 2 :
                   respons.sendRedirect("type_2_page");
              break;
              default :
                   repons.sendRedirect("/error500.jsp");
              break;
           }

        }else{

            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(your_jsp_relative_path).forward(request, respons);

        }
    }
}
```